# deleting old Access artifacts from MSysObjects

Tags: ms-access

I inherited an Access application that I have made some changes to.
When I start it up, I am getting several errors that appear to be referring
to old tables or queries. Nothing that is currently really part of the app
is wrong.

Here is the message:

```
The record source `~sq_cEmployee Certification Tracking ~sqclstAlerts` specified on this form does not exist.
```

I found something online that showed how to get Access to dump every
SQL object, and in that output, I see what I think are a bunch of garbage
queries that do NOT show up in the Object browser.

Here is an example of what I mean:

SQL name (4):

```
 ~sq_cEmployee Certification Tracking~sq_clstAlerts-----------------------------------------------
SELECT CertificationAlertsRaw.Alert AS Expr1
FROM CertificationAlertsRaw
WHERE (((CertificationAlertsRaw.Alert)="Yes"));
```

In this case, the `CertificationAlertsRaw` query has been deleted, at least as far as
the Object browser shows.  It was an old query that has been renamed.

Note the weird name with the tilde.

It almost looks like these are artifacts from a crash or else perhaps
an Access bug?

There are about 30+ of these.

If these things are, as I suspect, what is causing these error messages
at startup, how can I get rid of them, since they don't show up in the
Object browser window?

I also tried doing a "Compact and Repair" but that did not change anything.
Here are a few of the "Name" properties from these entries in MSysObjects:

```
~sq_cEmployee Certification Tracking Old~sq_ccboCertifications
~sq_cEmployee Certification Tracking Old~sq_clstHistory
~sq_cRoutineAssignments~sq_clstMaxTaskID
```

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queries that start with a tilde are from forms and reports. For example, if you use an sql string for a form, it will show up in Queries collection with a tilde.

```
Sub ListQueries()
For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    Debug.Print qdf.Name
Next
End Sub
```

You can delete them, but you have to be careful.

You would probably be better opening a fresh database and importing everything you see.

Answer (score 1):

```
~sq_cEmployee Certification Tracking~sq_clstAlerts
```

This means that the `lstAlerts` object (a listbox?) on the form Employee Certification Tracking is referencing the listed SQL statement:

```
SELECT CertificationAlertsRaw.Alert AS Expr1 FROM CertificationAlertsRaw WHERE (((CertificationAlertsRaw.Alert)="Yes"));
```

You would need to modify the record source of `lstAlerts` to point to another table since `CertificationAlertsRaw` is no longer available in the database.